# BambooBSC (Balanced Score Card) setup on Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans-8, bamboo-bsc

I am new to Java EE. Recently I had to implement an opensource balanced score card system for one of my clients. I stumbled upon [BambooBSC](https://github.com/billchen198318/bamboobsc). I successfully configured the project on a VM with the help of a VDI file (available on their github page).

Now I want to setup this project on my local machine. Since this project is based on J2EE platform, I already installed Apache Tomcat and Netbeans IDE on my local machine.

I cloned their repository on my system. And tried importing the project in my Netbeans IDE. Now the IDE shows me something like this.

[image: this]

I don't know what to do next. Seems like some external dependencies need to be provided to the project. But I am unable to figure it out. Please help me setup and run this project on my local machine. Will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you still need to help?

Comment: yes, i must understand how this project can be configured on local machine.

Comment: .... look for main file? Did you try running it? there are 9 subprojects, one of them must contain main file

Comment: Have you tried to go through [manual installation process](https://github.com/billchen198318/bamboobsc/blob/master/core-doc/install.pdf) for windows? There is no need to use any IDE. And please clarify what do you want to do: run the project on local machine to use it or work with code to modify the project?

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely need/want to work with Netbeans IDE?

Otherwise, you may consider using [Eclipse IDE](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

And follow this dedicated [official documentation](https://github.com/billchen198318/bamboobsc#build-development-environments).

Anyway, you can notice the information about **core-web**, **core-base** and **gsbsc-standard** projects.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: @Ali is everything OK for you?